# Fix block transparency and bounding box (1.10.2)

Tags: java, json, minecraft-forge

Here is what my candle block looks like:

[image: Candle block]

The problems are:

- The sandstone doesn't render
- Collision is a full block
- The selection box is a full block (selection box is a gray wireframe)

The methods provided by Forge to set these bounding boxes are deprecated, and

```
this.translucent = true;
this.fullBlock = false;
```

in the constructor do nothing.

More screenshots:

[image: Line of candles side view]

[image: Line of candles top view]

[image: Line of candles front view]

`BlockCandle.java`:

```
package com.otabi.firestar.toomuch.blocks;

import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.block.state.IBlockState;
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.world.IBlockAccess;

/**
 * Created by firestar115 on 10/22/16.
 */
public class BlockCandle extends BlockBase { // BlockBase only sets registry names and model locations

    public BlockCandle() {
        super(Material.CAKE, "candle");
        this.fullBlock = false;
        this.translucent = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNormalCube(IBlockState state, IBlockAccess world, BlockPos pos) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

`models/block/candle.json`:

```
{
    "__comment": "Model generated using MrCrayfish's Model Creator (https://mrcrayfish.com/tools?id=mc)",
    "textures": {
        "0": "toomuch:blocks/candle_base",
        "1": "toomuch:blocks/candle_wick"
    },
    "display": {
        "gui": {
            "rotation": [ 30, 225, 0 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
            "scale": [ 0.625, 0.625, 0.625 ]
        },
        "ground": {
            "rotation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 3, 0 ],
            "scale": [ 0.25, 0.25, 0.25 ]
        },
        "fixed": {
            "rotation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
            "scale": [ 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 ]
        },
        "thirdperson_righthand": {
            "rotation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 2.5, 0.5 ],
            "scale": [ 0.375, 0.375, 0.375 ]
        },
        "thirdperson_lefthand": {
            "rotation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 2.5, 0.5 ],
            "scale": [ 0.375, 0.375, 0.375 ]
        },
        "firstperson_righthand": {
            "rotation": [ 0, 45, 0 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 2.5, 0 ],
            "scale": [ 0.4, 0.4, 0.4 ]
        },
        "firstperson_lefthand": {
            "rotation": [ 0, 225, 0 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 2.5, 0 ],
            "scale": [ 0.4, 0.4, 0.4 ]
        }
    },
    "elements": [
        {
            "name": "Cube",
            "from": [ 6.50, 0.00, 6.50 ], 
            "to": [ 9.50, 8.00, 9.50 ], 
            "faces": {
                "north": { "texture": "#0", "uv": [ 0.00, 0.00, 3.00, 8.00 ] },
                "east": { "texture": "#0", "uv": [ 3.00, 8.00, 6.00, 16.00 ] },
                "south": { "texture": "#0", "uv": [ 6.00, 0.00, 9.00, 8.00 ] },
                "west": { "texture": "#0", "uv": [ 9.00, 8.00, 12.00, 16.00 ] },
                "up": { "texture": "#0", "uv": [ 0.00, 0.00, 3.00, 3.00 ] },
                "down": { "texture": "#0", "uv": [ 0.00, 0.00, 3.00, 3.00 ] }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Cube",
            "from": [ 7.50, 8.00, 7.50 ], 
            "to": [ 8.50, 10.00, 8.50 ], 
            "faces": {
                "north": { "texture": "#1", "uv": [ 0.00, 0.00, 1.00, 2.00 ] },
                "east": { "texture": "#1", "uv": [ 1.00, 1.00, 2.00, 3.00 ] },
                "south": { "texture": "#1", "uv": [ 2.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00 ] },
                "west": { "texture": "#1", "uv": [ 3.00, 3.00, 4.00, 5.00 ] },
                "up": { "texture": "#1", "uv": [ 4.00, 4.00, 5.00, 5.00 ] },
                "down": { "texture": "#1", "uv": [ 5.00, 5.00, 6.00, 6.00 ] }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

`blockstates/candle.json`:

```
{
    "forge_marker": 1,
    "defaults": {
        "textures": {
            "0": "toomuch:blocks/candle_base",
            "1": "toomuch:blocks/candle_wick"
        }
    },
    "variants": {
        "normal": {
            "model": "toomuch:candle"
        },
        "inventory": {
            "model": "toomuch:candle"
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Forge 1.10.2 12.18.2.2099.

Comment: where is your bounding box definition in your block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding bounding boxes?

```
public void setBlockBoundsBasedOnState(final IBlockAccess worldIn, final BlockPos pos) {
            this.setBlockBounds(0.25f, 0.125f, 0.25f, 0.75f, 0.875f, 0.75f);
        }

public void addCollisionBoxesToList(final World worldIn, final BlockPos pos, final IBlockState state, final AxisAlignedBB mask, final List list, final Entity collidingEntity) {
        this.setBlockBoundsBasedOnState((IBlockAccess)worldIn, pos);
        super.addCollisionBoxesToList(worldIn, pos, state, mask, list, collidingEntity);
    }
```

update for 1.10

`getCollisionBoundingBox(...)`, `getSelectedBoundingBox(...)`, `isFullCube(...)`, and `isOpaqueCube (...)`.

Comment: Would this also work for the entity collide method with a full block? Because it wouldn't detect collision, only entity walk.

Comment: yup, the collision boxes are for the entities, the blockbounds are for, well, the blockbounds.

Comment: My beehive block is a cube (in model) so if i use this to set the collision box to a cube it will work? I've heard that a bounding box >1 in the x and z directions is buggy. It will definitely work for my candle though.

Comment: the beehive box is a totally different question. Ask a new question for that case.

Comment: No such methods "setBlockBounds" or "addCollisionBoxesToList"

Comment: Hmmh, they must have changed that functionality/renamed that again. Ill need to research that in the forge changelogs

Comment: If they are added back in a later version of forge, I can switch. I am using the recommended version.

Comment: try `getCollisionBoundingBox(...)`, `getSelectedBoundingBox(...)`, `isFullCube(...)`, and `isOpaqueCube (...)`.